# Keep div in background during horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a bar chart. It's very wide so I use iScroll to scroll horizontally. I have horizontal lines behind the bar chart. As the user scrolls right, I want the lines to move with in the background too, without changing the width of the line container. So lines should always be visible as user scrolls left and right. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2zjK/) and code is here:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id='lineContainer'>
            <div class='line'></div>
            <div class='line'></div>
            <div class='line'></div>
            <div class='line'></div>
        </div>

        <div id='barChart'>
           <div class="child-element child1"></div>
           <div class="child-element child2"></div>
            <div class="child-element child3"></div>
           <div class="child-element child4"></div>
            <div class="child-element child5"></div>
            <div class="child-element child6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    div.line{
        border-bottom: thin red dotted;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }

    #lineContainer{
        position:absolute;
        width:200px;
    }

    #barChart{
            position:absolute;
    }

    .container {
       white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .child-element {
        min-width: 60px;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        margin-right:70px;
    }

    .child1 {
        background-color: purple;
    }
    .child2 {
        background-color: orange;
    }
    .child3 {
        background-color: black;
    }
    .child4 {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .child5 {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .child6 {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: don't forget to select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aswell as doing what [Alex Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25059112/3856902).

It might be wise to use `:nth-child` rather than `.child1` it might save you some work in the long run, or its just *the proper way of doing it.*

`div.child-element:nth-child(0) {}` etc

Answer (score 0):

try this code  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h2zjK/10/)

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
div.line{
    border-bottom: thin red dotted;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

#lineContainer{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
}

#barChart{
        position:absolute;
}

.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-element {
    min-width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right:70px;
}
.child-element:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
.child1 {
    background-color: purple;
}
.child2 {
    background-color: orange;
}
.child3 {
    background-color: black;
}
.child4 {
    background-color: green;
}
.child5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.child6 {
    background-color: red;
}
```